# Input ∩ Source Code

Tags: code-golf, quine

### Intro

The challenge is to create a program/function that prints the intersection of its own source code and a given string input. This is code golf and to be more precise:

- Let `I` be the input set

  - `{"a","b","c"}`
- Let `S` be the source code set

  - `{"b","f"}`
- Then the intersection is what they share

  - `I ∩ S = {"b"}`

### Input

Input is flexible. It should be able to handle the character encoding used for the source code.

### Output

Output is flexible. It should be the set of characters that the input and source code share. Also, [sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) are unordered collections of distinct objects. In summary:

- Output is flexible:

  - Could be any data structure (string or otherwise)
  - Could unordered
  - Could have a trailing `\n`
  - Should be distinct

### Restriction

Similar to [quine](/questions/tagged/quine) challenges, the program/function may not read its own source code and 0-byte solutions are not allowed.

### Examples

- **#1**

```
functor x(I){ return I ∩ self; }

Inputs                                Outputs
------                                -------
enter preformatted text here      ->  {"e","n","t","r","f","o","x"}

["Albrt"," Einstin"]              ->  {"l","r","t","n","s"}
```

- **#2**

```
(_)->_&"(_)->&\"\\"

Inputs                                Outputs
------                                -------
"Security at the expense of       ->  "
usability comes at the expense 
of security."

(0____0)                          ->  (_)
```

- **#3**

```
ಠa益длф


Inputs                                Outputs
------                                -------
Far out in the uncharted backwaters ->"a"    
of the unfashionable end of the 
Western Spiral arm of the Galaxy lies 
a small unregarded yellow sun. 
Orbiting this at a distance of roughly 
ninety-eight million miles is an 
utterly insignificant little blue-green 
planet whose ape-descended life forms 
are so amazingly primitive that they 
still think digital watches are a pretty 
neat idea.

(ノಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻                      ->"ಠ益"
```

### Test Cases

```
Albert Einstein

\__( O__O)_/

!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?

1234567890-=[]\;',./

(ノಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻

“¤>%,oỊȤʠ“ØụĊ5D³ṃṠɼQ»j;Ç;“;}¶”

┬──┬ ノ( ゜-゜ノ)

Far out in the uncharted backwaters of the unfashionable end of the Western Spiral arm of the Galaxy lies a small unregarded yellow sun. Orbiting this at a distance of roughly ninety-eight million miles is an utterly insignificant little blue-green planet whose ape-descended life forms are so amazingly primitive that they still think digital watches are a pretty neat idea.
```

**Update**

- [16-08-10]: [sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) are unordered collections of distinct objects
- [16-08-10]: trailing newline is acceptable

Comment: May the output contain duplicate characters?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma From examples #1, #2 and #3 it appears not

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Sorry for the ambiguity, sets (in the mathematical sense) ignore order and have no repetition.

Comment: Is a trailing newline acceptable when printing the output?

Comment: @Dennis Yes, a trailing newline is acceptable.

Comment: Congratulations for coming up with a [generalised quine](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8595/8478) where the best solutions are not based on the language's standard quine. :)

Comment: If a set should not have repetition, shouldn't the input sets also not contain repetition? Or is the input actually not a set?

Comment: @user81655 When I said "Let `I` be the input set" I meant that `I` is the set of the input not that the input is a set

Comment: Are sets typically ordered or not? that is, does the order of the output matter?

Comment: @cat Sets are unordered so the order of the output does not matter.

Comment: TBH, the definition of "set" is **not** ambiguous in any way.

Comment: @Andrea I'm sorry, did you mean the English definition is unambiguous or the mathematical definition? :P

Comment: Are they different? A set is an unordered collection of non repeating elements. The problem defined in the Q was clear before adding the clarification. :) Especially for people who write code which are expected to know the definition of a "set" in any programming language.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto The duplicate knives in my 40-piece silverware set beg to differ...

Comment: @NonlinearFruit eheh... That is another kind of set that has nothing to do with math or programming. I guess a Hollywood movie set could beg to differ as well. :)

Answer (score 24):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“Ṿf”Ṿf
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCc4bm-ZuKAneG5vmY&input=&args=J-KAnOG5vmbigJ3hub5mIGFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6Jw)

#### How it works

```
“Ṿf”Ṿf  Main link. Argument: s (string)

“Ṿf”    Set the return value to 'Ṿf'.
    Ṿ   Uneval; yield '“Ṿf”'.
     f  Filter; remove the characters from '“Ṿf”' that do not appear in s.
```

Answer (score 14):

### Python 3, 44 bytes

Thanks Karl for saving me one byte :-)
Thanks Dada for saving me two bytes!

I think this works, but it's my first quine challenge so I'm not 100% sure. :\

```
print(set("printseu()&'"+'+"')&set(input()))
```

Lambda version with 43 bytes:
`lambda a:set(" lambdaset()&'"+':+"')&set(a)`

Comment: `'eroticpuns\()&\''` is shorter than adding the strings. (escaped the `'` but then you need a additional `\\`) Why is the dot there?

Comment: woops, the `.` was a relic from less golfed code. Using backslash doesn't work because then the output from `\\` is `\\\`, and duplicating the input character isn't allowed, I think.

Comment: Your lambda is missing the `:`.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis. My eyes start clouding over after trying to find all the characters in the program ;)

Comment: @KarlKastor is that letters configuration really random?  
@Jeremy Am I missing something or `c` and `o` aren't needed in the first set?

Comment: thjx @Dada! The reason I've had these random chars still in there is because my first crack used `set.intersection` instead of the ampersand.

Comment: @KarlKastor ahah, you're pretty good at that. Not sure if it's really appropriate on SE/PPCG tho

Comment: @Dada: If you'd prefer, it could be `inspectour`, `nicestupor`, `poeticurns`, `nopictures`, `recountspi`, or `inputscore`. Or for the new one you might use `prunesit` (an accurate description of what code golfers do!), `ipunster`, or `nursepit` among others.

Comment: You can get down to 40 with set unpacking `print({*'''printu()&'{}*'''}&{*input()})`.

Comment: Or 36 with a lambda `lambda a:{*''' lambda&':{}*'''}&{*a}`.

Comment: @MorganThrapp thanks! That's quite a significant improvement, I don't feel it's right for me to take credit for it.

Comment: @Jeremy Up to you. It's the same algorithm, which is usually what I use to determine if I feel okay with taking a suggestion or not.

Comment: With implicit string concatenation, you can take out both of the +s: `print(set("printseu()&'"'"')&set(input()))`. If you put two string literals next to each other, they're concatenated: `"here and " 'there' == 'here and there'`

Answer (score 11):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 8 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
'∩''⊢'∩⊢
```

`∩` is returns those characters from the left argument that are present in the right argument (if the **left** argument has no duplicates – as in this case – then the result also has no duplicates

`⊢` is the argument

Then the string just has those two plus the quote character (doubled, as it is in a string).

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28%27%u2229%27%27%u22A2%27%u2229%u22A2%29%A8%27functor%20x%28I%29%7B%20return%20I%20%u2229%20self%3B%20%7D%27%20%271234567890-%3D%5B%5D%5C%3B%27%27%2C./%27%20%27%5C__%28%20O__O%29_/%27&run)

Answer (score 10):

## GolfScript, 6 bytes

```
"`&"`&
```

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=ImAmImAm&input=ImAmImAmIDEyMzQ1Njc4OTA)

#### How it works

```
        # (implicit) Push the input on the stack.
"`&"    # Push the string '`&' on the stack.
   `    # Inspect; turn the string into '"`&"'.
     &  # Perform set intersection.
```

Comment: So that's how you can get quotes into the string without having to add backslash.

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 56, 55 bytes

**"*French*" / Unicode version** (55 bytes)

```perl6
say perl q.say perlq∩$*IN\\\.comb:..comb∩$*IN.comb:
```

**"*Texas*" / ASCII versions** (56 bytes)

```perl6
say (q.sayq(&) $*IN\\\.combperl..comb (&)$*IN.comb).perl
```

```perl6
say perl q.sayq(&) $*IN\\\.comb:perl..comb (&)$*IN.comb:
```

## Non-golfed:

```perl6
my \Source = 'my \\Source = \'say ( $*IN.comb.Set ∩ Source.comb.Set ).perl\'';
say ( $*IN.comb.Set ∩ Source.comb.Set ).perl
```

## Examples:

```sh
$ echo -n 'say perl q.say perlq∩$*IN\\\.comb:..comb∩$*IN.comb:' > test-unicode.p6

$ echo -n 'say (q.sayq(&) $*IN\\\.combperl..comb (&)$*IN.comb).perl' > test-ascii.p6

$ perl6 test-ascii.p6 <<< 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
set("p","a","l","r","c","q","b","s","e","m","y","o")

$ perl6 test-unicode.p6 < test-unicode.p6
set("\\","I","p"," ","a","c","l","r","q","b","∩","*","s","m","e",".","y",":","o","N","\$")

$ perl6 test-ascii.p6 < test-ascii.p6
set("p","\\","I"," ","a","l","r","c","q","b",")","*","s","e","m","\&",".","(","y","o","N","\$")

$ perl6 test-ascii.p6 < test-unicode.p6
set("p","\\","I"," ","a","l","r","c","q","b","*","s","e","m",".","y","o","N","\$")

$ perl6 test-unicode.p6 <<< 'Albert Einstein'
set(" ","l","r","b","s","e")

$ perl6 test-unicode.p6 <<< '\__( O__O)_/'
set("\\"," ")

$ perl6 test-ascii.p6 <<< '!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?'
set(")","*","\&","(","\$")

$ perl6 test-unicode.p6 <<< "1234567890-=[]\\;',./"
set("\\",".")

$ perl6 test-unicode.p6 <<< '(ノಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻'
set()

“¤>%,oỊȤʠ“ØụĊ5D³ṃṠɼQ»j;Ç;“;}¶”
set("o")

$ perl6 test-unicode.p6 <<< '┬──┬ ノ( ゜-゜ノ)'
set(" ")


$ perl6 test-ascii.p6 <<< 'Far out in the uncharted backwaters of the unfashionable end of the Western Spiral arm of the Galaxy lies a small unregarded yellow sun. Orbiting this at a distance of roughly ninety-eight million miles is an utterly insignificant little blue-green planet whose ape-descended life forms are so amazingly primitive that they still think digital watches are a pretty neat idea.'
set("p"," ","a","l","r","c","b","s","e","m",".","y","o")
```

Comment: Doesn't `$*PROGRAM` access the source code of the program, and thus violate the rules?

Comment: @celtschk I should have re-read the question before posting, fixed. ( Technically the compiler could see that `$*PROGRAM` is read from and store the entire source as a string in the compiled program, which would have put it into a grey area )

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2, <s>56</s> <s>46</s> 39 Bytes

*-1 Byte thanks to @Jeremy*

```
lambda a:set(':&()smelt\ bad\'')&set(a)
```

anonymous lambda function, takes a string, returns a set

old version:

```
lambda x,w=set('newmatrixbuspdl_:-)(=,\ \''):w-(w-set(x))
```

Comment: I like this, but it returns two backslashes on `\\\` instead of just one.

Comment: Also, i think you can save a byte by changing the name of the lambda to `a`

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks for tip, `'\\'` is just Python's way of representing a backslash in string form, because a single one would escape the end quote, so you have to escape the backslash with a backslash to make it work. Type `print '\\'` and you'll see that it is just the representation for one backslash.

Comment: You can get to 36 with `lambda a:{*''' lambda&':{}*'''}&{*a}`.

Comment: @MorganThrapp 35 `lambda a:{*' lambda&\\\':{}*'}&{*a}`

Comment: @MorganThrapp: Which Python version are you using? Even in Python3 i get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: It only works in 3.5 and on.

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
'X&'''X&
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=J1gmJycnWCY&input=J0xldHRlciAnJ1gnJyBpcyBYLXRyYSBmdW4hJw)

Input is a string enclosed in single quotes. If the string contains a single-quote symbol, it should be duplicated to escape it.

#### Explanation

```
'X&'''   % Push string with the three characters used by the program. The single-quote 
         % symbol needs to be escaped by duplicating it
X&       % Take input implicitly. Set intersection. Display implicitly
```

Answer (score 7):

### Actually, 6 bytes

```
`∩è`è∩
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=YOKIqcOoYMOo4oip&input=ImFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6XCInYCI)

Explanation:

```
`∩è`è∩
`∩è`    push the function `∩è` (which contains every character in the source code except '`')
    è   repr (same as Python repr - leaves "`∩è`", which contains every character in the source code)
      ∩ set intersection with input
```

Answer (score 5):

## C, 142 bytes

```
main(i){char*p,a[]="remain([*]){fought?>:01;,\\\"=capsv+-l}";for(;(i=getchar())>=0;p?putchar(i),memmove(p,p+1,a+strlen(a)-p):0)p=strchr(a,i);}
```

[Try it on ideone](http://ideone.com/sdlhRR).

Comment: An ungolfed version and/or explanation would be great!

Comment: You could have used `sizeof a` instead of `strlen(a)` for one byte saved, but even better is to give the array a known size: `a[99]="..."`, and replace `strlen(a)` by `99` to shave off 5 bytes.

Comment: Another 3 or 4 bytes can be saved by replacing `(i=getchar())>=0` with `read(0,&i,1)`. This works on little-endian machines. `i` is initialized to 1 if you don't run the program with any arguments. If you want it to work on big-endian machines as well, remove i from the argument list of `main()` and declare it inside the body as a char (but then you save only 3 bytes). `read()` conveniently returns 0 on EOF.

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell (30 bytes)

This is such a boring solution... But I couldn't do better. :(

```hs
filter(`elem`"f(term)\"i`l\\")
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 23 bytes

```
:{e.~e":{}e~\"fd\."}fd.
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OntlLn5lIjp7fWV-XCJmZFwuIn1mZC4&input=IiFAIyQlXiYqKClfK3t9fDpcIjw-PzpcOiI&args=Wg)

#### Explanation

```
:{                 }f      Find all chars that verify the predicate below
                     d.    Remove duplicates and output

  e.                       Take a char from the input ; this is our output…
    ~e":{}e~\"fd\."        … if that char is in the string :{}e~"fd. (the first \ is here
                               to escape the ")
```

Comment: Can you have a look at our chatroom?

Comment: +1 for moustache man `:{` and surprised moustache man `:{}`

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

Code:

```
"'ÃJÙ"'"JÃÙ
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=IifDg0rDmSInIkrDg8OZ&input=SGVsbG8sICInw4NKIiciSsODLCBXb3JsZCE).

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

**1 byte thanks to Sp3000**

```
@Q"\Q@\"
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40Q%22%5CQ%40%5C%22&input=%22+%21%5C%22%23%24%25%26%27%28%29%2a%2B%2C-.%2F0123456789%3A%3B%3C%3D%3E%3F%40ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%5B%5C%5D%5E_%60abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%7B%7C%7D~+%21%5C%22%23%24%25%26%27%28%29%2a%2B%2C-.%2F0123456789%3A%3B%3C%3D%3E%3F%40ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%5B%5C%5D%5E_%60abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%7B%7C%7D~%22&debug=0)

```
@Q"\Q@\"
@Q"\Q@\""   implicit string ending

@Q           intersect the input with
  "\Q@\""   the string containing '\', 'Q', '@', '"'.
```

Comment: `@z"z\"@` is 1 byte shorter.

Comment: @drobilc That would miss out the ``\``.

Comment: oh, yeah, totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>45 50 41 39 37 34</s> 29 bytes

-9 bytes thanks to Geoff Reedy
-4 bytes thanks to Dennis
-5 bytes thanks to Nahuel Fouilleul

```bash
grep -o '[] [|\'\'grepouniq-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P70otUBBN19BPTpWIbomRj1GHSSSX5qXWagb@/9/anpBUWIMAA)

Comment: Don't you only need one grep command?

Comment: @GeoffReedy The first grep command splits the input into one character per line.

Comment: Right but couldn't the -o be put on to the second grep

Comment: You're right, and that saves having to check for the '.'. Thanks!

Comment: `grep -o '[] [|\'\'greposrtu-]|sort -u` should work.

Comment: Is there something wrong with my suggestion? It seems to save 2 bytes over your current approach.

Comment: @Titus I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Your expression contains backslashes. Are backslashes matched in the filtering process?

Comment: @Titus After BASH does it's thing, grep gets `-o` and `[] [|\'grepouniq-]`. So it is looking for anything of these: `[` `]` `{space}` `[` `|` `{slash}` `'` `g` `r` `e` `p` `o` `u` `n` `i` `q` `-` `]`.

Comment: @Titus does that help?

Comment: why `uniq` is used? uniq filters only adjacent matching lines (if sorted for example)

Comment: I'm not sure why I had `uniq`. Input will only have 1 of each character (because it's a set), so I don't need remove duplicates. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 8 bytes

```
"`q&"`q&
```

[Try it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22%60r%26%22%60r%26)

Explanation:

```
"`q&"    e# Push that string to the stack
     `   e# Stringify, pops the string and pushes "\"`r&\"" to the stack
      q  e# Pushes the input to the stack
       & e# Union, pops two elements and pushes a list of every element that is contained in both.
```

Answer (score 4):

## Retina, <s>21</s> 20 bytes

Removes characters not in the source code, then removes duplicate characters.

```
[^Ds.n\n[-a_-]

Ds`.
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=W15Ecy5uXG5bLWFfLV0KCkRzYC4&input=RApgCl4Kbg)

Comment: Your source code contains a linefeed (your output doesn't).

Comment: I had basically the same solution earlier but forgot to post it. You can save a few bytes with the range `[-a` (and then include an underscore and a hyphen and drop the backtick on the second line). But for future reference, `]` wouldn't need escaping if you put it as the first character. Oh and for niceness, you can swap the two stages to avoid the trailing linefeed.

Comment: @MartinEnder This still doesn't deduplicate line feeds, is that a problem?

Comment: Oh you're right, I didn't notice that. You'll have to add `s` to the options of `D` and the character class then.

Answer (score 4):

## C#, 36 bytes

```
s=>s.Intersect("s=>.Interc(\"\\);");
```

Intended cast is `Func<string, IEnumerable<char>>` (`string` input, `IEnumerable<char>` output).

Comment: @Kobi [Intersect<TSource> enumerates _first_, collecting all **distinct elements** of that sequence. It then enumerates _second_, marking those elements that occur in both sequences.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). _second_ is already distinct therefore `Intersect` will return only distinct elements.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 35 bytes

```
Characters@"\"#&@C\acehrst⋂"⋂#&
```

Anonymous function. Ignore any generated messages. Takes a list of characters as input and returns a list of characters as output. The Unicode character is U+22C2 for `\[Intersection]`.

Answer (score 4):

## Vim, <s>78 68 78 79</s> 61 keystrokes

Completely changed my approach:

```
oo/\$kjxd<esc>/o<cr>xj$/\/<cr>xj$/\\<cr>xj$/$<cr>xj$/k<cr>xj$/x<cr>xj$/j<cr>xj$/d<cr>xkdd
```

How it works:

First, it makes a line with all the program characters, then, it finds the first instance of each of the program characters, which is either in the input, if the input and output intersect, or the output if they don't, deletes it, moves to the last character of the file (so it wraps around) and does that for each unique character in source, except d, where instead of moving to the end of the file, it finishes up by deleting the input

Comment: Backslash is in your code but doesn´t seem to be in your string.

Comment: Isn't it the third?

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell v4+, <s>122</s> 104 bytes

```
([char[]]($args[0]+'acegfhmnoprstu012|][()"?+_,.$-{0}{1}{2}'-f("'","}","{"))|group|?{$_.count-gt1}).name
```

Ugh. Quines or quine-like code in PowerShell sucks, because the string replacement formatting is so clunky.

The string `ace...{2}` in the middle is every character that's present in the rest of the code. The `{0}{1}{2}` is used in conjunction with the `-f`ormat operator to pull the `'{}` characters into the string.

That's combined as a char-array with the input `$args`, then fed into the pipeline. The first stop is `Group-Object` which (essentially) creates a hashtable of the input objects and how many times they occur in the input. That's piped to `|?{...}` the `Where-Object` to only select those items that have a `.count` greater than `1`. We encapsulate that in parens, and pluck out the `.Name` portion of the hashtable (which is where the v4+ requirement comes into play, otherwise we'd need an additional `|Select Name` stage to the pipeline).

Those elements are left on the pipeline (as an array), and printing is implicit.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>59</s> 57 bytes

```js
f=
t=>[..."\"().=>O[\\]defilnrtx~"].filter(e=>~t.indexOf(e))
;
```

```html
<input placeholder=Input oninput=o.value=f(this.value).join``><input placeholder=Output id=o>
```

Returns an array of characters present in both the original string/character array and the source code. Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @user81655.

Comment: `f=s=>[...new Set(f+'')]...` could save bytes.

Comment: Or even shorter: `f=s=>[...s].filter(c=>(new Set(f+'')).has(c))`

Comment: @user81655 At least in Firefox, `f+''` works by reading `f`'s source code. (In certain cases you could get Firefox to crash by changing the source file and then attempting to stringify a function loaded from it.)

Comment: @user81655 Your second example fails when `s` has repeated elements, and `indexOf` is shorter than `new Set` anyway.

Comment: In that case, you could try saving chars (like changing the `c` parameter to a character that is already in the list).

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the input set follows the same set rules (no duplicates).

Comment: @user81655 Thanks for that `c` tip, but check the test cases for duplicates, I think you might find some.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. The comments clarifying that a set does not contain duplicates seem to contradict the test cases. If the input is in fact a set, you could even take it as a `Set` then do `s.has(c)` inside the filter. You can change the `s` to another character as well by the way.

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, 44 bytes

```py
x='c=set;print c(`x`)&c(raw_input())';exec x
```

Just for fun, here's a quine-like full program submission. Outputs the string representation of a Python 2 set.

Answer (score 3):

### sed, 47 characters

```
:s;st[^])(*\1.s2t:[;^]tt;st\(.\)\(.*\1\)t\2t;ts
```

I'm a little disappointed at how long this came out to be, especially the bit to remove repeated characters.

Comment: Which version of sed is this? GNU sed says ``sed: -e expression #1, char 47: unterminated `s' command``.

Comment: 43 bytes including 1 for -r: `sed -r ':;ss[^][str().*\12;:^]ss;ss(.)(.*\1)s\2s;t'`    i wrote it before noticing yours and it turned out to be very similar

Comment: @Dennis fixed; turned out having a : after the [ caused it to try and parse a character class

Comment: @izabera nice, I'm quite surprised that the : command doesn't actually need a label and that it changes the meaning of t without a label

Comment: yeah it's a gnuism

Comment: Hm, that works well for a single line, but it breaks if there's more than one.

Answer (score 3):

## Matlab, 37 bytes

Quite simple:

Uses the builtin `intersect` to find the intersection. The source code is hard coded. Input must be given inside quotation marks `''`

```
intersect(input(''),'''intersc(pu),')
```

Comment: You should've used an anonymous function...[beat you by 5 bytes](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104062/32352)

Comment: Hehe, I guess that wasn't my best golf...

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (Chrome 58 on OS X 10), <s>12654</s> <s>12426</s> 11992 Bytes

<s>https://paste.ubuntu.com/25593218/</s>

<s>https://paste.ubuntu.com/25595798/</s>

https://paste.ubuntu.com/25595831/

The original code:

```
var t=prompt();"!+()[]".split("").forEach(function(f){if(t.includes(f))alert(f)})
```

This was then converted into a programming style called jsfk which only uses these six characters:

```
(+)[!]
```

using an online compiler.

Comment: If [jsfk](http://www.jsfuck.com) is the language, you should use that in the header instead of Javascript.

Comment: @NonlinearFruit jsfk is a programming **style**. It is valid javascript

Answer (score 2):

## q (38 bytes)

Reads from `stdin`

```
"readint0\\\" "inter read0 0
```

edit: was missing backslash

Comment: I'm not familiar with q, could you add a link?

Comment: sure, http://code.kx.com

Answer (score 2):

## R, 129 bytes

```
f=function(s){b=strsplit("f=unctio(s){arpl;,[1]b\\\"qemh0T}",c())[[1]];cat(b[unique(pmatch(strsplit(s,c())[[1]],b,0,T))],sep="")}
```

If I ungolf it, it needs to have weird things changed like a newline in the string for `b`. Anyhow, its super simple -- builds a vector with all characters in the function in it. Then it pulls the input into a vector, and checks membership.

Comment: you haven't visited the site in almost a year, but `f=function(s)cat(instersect(strsplit(s,"")[[1]],strsplit("f=unctio(s)aerpl,\\\"[1]","")[[1]]),sep="")` is 101 bytes, and I think the I/O format can be simpler, without `cat`...

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 34 + `n` flag = 35 bytes

Doesn't exactly work with multi-lined input, since `-n` causes the program to process STDIN line-by-line. There aren't newlines in this code, but trying to input something like that will output multiple arrays instead of one. If that is not good according to spec, please inform me and I will fix.

```
p $_.chars&"\\\"p $_.chars&".chars
```

Answer (score 2):

### Java 8 lambda, <s>152</s> <s>142</s> 140 characters

Quite short:

```
s->s.chars().mapToObj(i->(char)i).filter(c->"COSTab\"\\cefh(i)j+l-mn.oprstuv>".contains(""+c)).collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet())
```

Or ungolfed over here:

```
public class Q89400 {

    static Set<Character> inAndQuine(String in) {
        return in.chars()
                .mapToObj(i->(char)i)
                .filter(c->"COSTab\"\\cefh(i)j+l-mn.oprstuv>".contains(""+c))
                .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet());

    }
}
```

Of course the ungolfed solution is wrong, as it doesn't match the curly brackets and some more characters, it's just their for the sake of completeness.

The function takes input as a `String` and returns a `java.util.Set<Character>` containing the characters which are present in both input and source.

**Updates**

It turned out that the solution wasn't working. I thought `String#contains` tests for a regex match but it is just a literal matching. I added some escaping to quote the characters like `.` but this wasn't necessary but ruined everything instead. Now without this escaping we save some characters and now it actually works :)

Thanks to @NonlinearFruit for reminding me of using one-character variables.

Comment: Rename `in` to be a single letter like `a`

Comment: @NonlinearFruit you're right :O how could I forget about that?!

Answer (score 2):

### [ListSharp](https://github.com/timopomer/ListSharp), 222 bytes

```
STRG S=READ[<here>+"\\S.txt"]
ROWS T=ROWSPLIT S BY [""]
ROWS R=ROWSPLIT "STRG =EAD[<her>+\".tx]OWPLIBYCFMHVNc#isn()oay\r\n" BY [""]
ROWS R=SELECT FROM T WHERE[EVERY STRG IS ANY STRG IN R]
SHOW=<c#R.Distinct().ToArray()c#>
```

***ridiculous but im entertained***

Answer (score 2):

## [SQF](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/SQF_syntax), <s>71</s> <s>69</s> 64 bytes

Using the file-as-a-function format:

```
i="-_h ;""=()sSplitrng"splitString"";i-(i-(_this splitString""))
```

Call as `"STRING" call NAME_OF_COMPILED_FUNCTION`

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>6</s> 8 Bytes

```
{@"{@\"\
```

Expects input as a string.

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%7B%40%22%7B%40%5C%22%5C&input=%22D%40n%5C%22%22&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
 @     Q    Intersect implied input with:
  "{@\"\     The string containing {@"\
{          and then remove duplicates.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't remove duplicates.

Comment: Fixed!  Unfortunately, that costs two additional bytes, tying it with the other Pyth answer.

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, 32 bytes

```
@(t)intersect(t,'@(t)inersc,''')
```

Essentially the same as Stewie Griffin's approach (the `intersect` built-in is hard to avoid), but this edition saves an entire 5 bytes over his by taking the input as an anonymous function, with the variable name `t` chosen to occur within `intersect` (any other character in that string would have done as well). Call as `ans('yourInput')`.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>131</s> <s>129</s> 131 bytes

```java
a->{java.util.Set r=new java.util.HashSet();for(String s:a)if("a->{jv.utilSe r=nwHsh();fog:\"\\cd}".contains(s))r.add(s);return r;}
```

+2 bytes again due to a bug-fix

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##lZNLb9NAEMfv/RRDeNnQmGd5NG0A8eqFVigHDk2JJvbE3nS9jnbXCaFEKvSA1AOnHJAoUpHKrSeQkKrAJeUAfAqSCvExwiRtpSLEIZK99npm/vOb9UwV65hNaqSqwfLAl2gMPEChViYAhLKkK@gTzA@3AFX29VIrpFcgO3M7Qo0@u@TBdwpWCxUuLgG6OfZtTfBiLFrhwzwomIUBZvMrfwmAnlXUOCI6hybi746bqyT6QBHMNLqi4mRG4fWRY4GGoY05E41cw@liplj0g1bG8xNlGd44xnW1h0HALzlNNtUKdK41GKLxVUvLksEO@OqJCCDmsKNF7BdcaBpLsZek1quxyUrlKM93MrdkmbSFu5zKklAZz9SksE4m47qj8v8fWSyWSg4slEoLbuncGHHHbh4/cfLxqTOOWzq70nrGJc/kb4wRf@HipctTV65eu34@O7u4VCzmTk964@R39tZe/fyw@fvNOq8ub359eddvd/rt57yOodNf3ehu5U9OJr3O@retH5u8333d67z/uj51p/uxt7PW29n8/vlht1PN7b7MsTXX6n7qr74dJ0V7u99eHV3bwKQO7L3YyPLN7@4YOvdQA3/kMQAbEaTK54a3FEAZ/eUGcuMbSCoHtgr3rkgUliUBqeDQ8IhYm5uvUBMaJaCODy33UeKTJkhBBhBMjFKyjKYQdcA5miRl0gCTKg8WdFnY4SzYSLCzZf9AcPMqnkxW00kaRrIJSiiyzSyJMLIQCymZZ/jkBMMwBallFnbkrhWhEhXho7JMYC1Dl2VK2VATKahJZCVoRIkhwBplAzI@F8VYUlQIeDpjFtQEJgGM8SmzsSwfXsycdWJOhuQimzxizDHkVsvMHArLh8BH50e0L4AcRdYyPHGICAi9f/5Qa6I1@AM)

```java
a->{                    // Method with String-array parameter and Set return-type
  java.util.Set r=new java.util.HashSet();
                        //  The result Set
  for(String s:a)       //  Loop over the input String-array
    if("a->{jv.utilSe r=nwHsh();fog:\"\\cd}".contains(s))
                        //   If the current character is part of the source-code:
      r.add(s);         //    Add it to the Set
                        //  End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
  return r;             //  Return the result-Set
}                       // End of method
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog (newer)](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 18 bytes

```
{∈"{∈\\\"&}ˢd"&}ˢd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY0xbsMwDEWv8qEhaYFOHbN1a5deIMogR0wkVJYMkYZhpBmSocg5fILcw7fwRVylRkHifeKD@L/KZu/6kI6v8/Rzn66Xcejm03S7qQe01mp1Hge7cJ636q3iFFqh0OMzifPxqF7UU1xOsEsdo21gGCaC6kZ6BM@C7e65PJa1K1u4OX2fi/SlZBz@pxhao3AcUk1Lov@L67w4VGb/xcGwI0bVCj7gUkPwsmaw@BCg1cFH0o@ad5MtJKEYFgYx5doEBBKhDB/hKJPa/QI)

It's [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180402/85334) plus the de-duplication predicate. Doesn't necessarily beat Fatalize's solution since his is in an older and very different version of the language.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 38 bytes

```perl6
<say .comb∩$*IN.comb#<>~EVAL>~~.EVAL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/9@mOLFSQS85PzfpUcdKFS1PPzBb2cauzjXM0ceurk4PRBOrDgA)

The generalised quine still manages to beat out  the trivial program by a few bytes

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 41 bytes

```perl6
say <$*. <>INabcmosy∩>.comb∩$*IN.comb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVLBRkVLT8HGztMvMSk5N7@48lHHSju95PzcJCBDRcvTD8xGKLVRIKAUAA)

Answer (score 2):

### [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 12 bytes

```
34C+t"34C+tt
```

### Explanation

```
34C+t"       % Everyone in the execution sequence excluding a quote
      34C+   % Add a (") quote
          t  % Trim out everything in this string in input
           t % Trim the string so that the intersection is kept
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 33 bytes

```python
lambda a:{*"\"\lambd* :{}&"}&{*a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHRqlpLKUYpBszVUrCqrlVTqlWr1kqs/V9QlJlXopGmoZSRmpOTrxCeX5SToqSp@R8A)

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 48 bytes

First thing I though of. It can probably be golfed more.

Input comes from sdtin. Output goes to stdout as a set object

```
print set(raw_input())&set("raw_pint se(u)\&\"")
```

Comment: Is this 40 bytes?

Comment: doesn't work for input `\\`

Comment: @Jeremy You're right, I forgot to update that. It's 47.

Comment: @KarlKastor Fixed

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 61 bytes

```php
<?=preg_filter("_<\?=[aefiglprtv$(\_[\],)\\;1\"]_",$argv[1]);
```

takes input from first command line argument.

**no regex, 74 bytes**

```php
for(;""<$c=$argv[1][$i++];)if(strstr("aceghiosrtv()$<=[1]\;\"",$c))echo$c;
```

takes input from first command line argument. Run with `-nr`.

Note: `;` needs no escaping; so PHP takes the backslash before the semicolon literally.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 58 bytes

```java
s->s.filter("s->.filter(\"\\:cona)d"::contains).distinct()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVRNjxtFED2zv6IwBGYgnvAVPuyNA0qAEzFoQRwywSrP1Njt7ekedbe9mLDSQg5Ie@C0BySCtEjhlhNISNHCZcMB@BWsI8TPWN7Y3uxK3oxmprunXr161V01I55w01ZiRvnmcTXua5VRptl7@oCVodtra4TLBw4wFMqwphFcknFQOinGJgvKmuQTw27arcRxsG79FOCDEy6TjfmwjkGZQadDN@jKsW92fFIoHcRFDSxO5mkjTVuZNRznjVY9CdDh4yRXPiiEi@LjWlF7IaxyasJBTgROrMopiA/RIhb5GCnQ8tqY@iBlYschgZ8J2kQ3Eq4qPY18ktlcPrT46qM4Kbn62Hb7o@jakB1n0NVqBVsv/Ny4pG@1JqzH0i3iGP5aC@StJH9tYbDOJyPwwy2K47g9V7W9zGKx72eTKJH1MsrNW8Rn05jn13hH98UFehebE0SZxpLxFJCmvV5E3V6vG/curZqffvuZZy989twLUdx78fb2l620sd65ugp7@ZVXX7v8@htvvvVS88rNW2nafv5icg5b9OjOt//8vP/f97t4x1j8@/uPs72D2d5XeK/CZzt3D@91Lly0Rwe7f977ex/rh98dHfz0x@7l64e/HD24c/Rg/6/fPjo8GLUfftOGtb19@Ots54dzmPbuz/Z25vd9QtyIHn19t4kH83gV/h47wvkTSjsMhVC/ONMgOfU529xCJTlPtljaCvZDVDf3tZCY/MTwKZjEGdqolEM7sCtPLO@z5s@npJV4YvIlaw0aJwN2OWJMRWu7RX5sEuq6vgp1hYahAjgAX1c4m0xqNmfHg6GeEspFwrQpajAMVCqtoaceEaB2MzQO0AIgykANjCpUxiZAQQgQ3UdxNgdOxFClGUy0NbReiCtp5uIzJAVZWhVChXUlCB1ayRKX/AW0gRZ9UkLnRKATIpHkFGUKHbVuswnNAxWwCdi6bCgLAoaXhADxAheVCyf1Qaw9dU7/rRzQE/4E5@H8KfCsV1r7PfZMn/ATaTzuwO3j/wE)

Accepts the input as `Stream<String>`, whereas each character of the input is a stream element, and returns a filtered, distinct stream.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>14</s> 15 bytes

My very first "proper" quine. At long fecking last!

```
oQ+"oQ+ ¬â"Q ¬â
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=b1ErIm9RKyCs4iJRIKzi&input=J09xb1ErIm9RKyCs4iJRIKziJw==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 91 bytes

Old challenge, but still lacking a Lua solution, so...

```lua
s=...(" s=.(\\\"):gub,fnctiod1awre"):gsub(".",function(c)c=s:find(c,1,1)and io.write(c)end)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZA9j9swDIb/CpHJARIDWQ@49Tp26NAlCy3RNhGZCiSqru/P@163l4mA3g89ZGq87/W97/vuRJjd/X4/nd@mNlxGC6453ngtcjzVNnSn/nQZ2z/BunAO7/VtVItduNwutzNbJM39WtQFqlg87/v@wYVyc1Ijn4WQnrm4RBo4PFZ2KZXy@K2NXGd085CEkH8Jv6XCZ/TrqYUTcVleyg9O/HejpFKJqS6cEmqKTFwi/tgkpbxSbdbTzzKoq03IKcwOf9TqbEGOtpLbNKeNTE18u4pOs9OiKYHnmPjgiBk1BwuMalUn01EDm4PAHdBDanKdiojRMzGaaJ1zFeKnXKPUgKWAlXQUGnNZUFiEaiZe@BNsqH0WXcD5R8AJSCy5UXVwHNz2APOkjiPgdGGW/wWMlLgDXhDRKNx/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 18 bytes

```
'''&()[-.'&([-.-.)
```

#### How it works

```
 ''&()[-.           the character set, '' stands for '
          &         is the left operand
           ([    )  the set> itself, ignore <the input
           (   -.)  the set> except any characters in <the input
                      (the wrong ones remain)
           ( -.  )  the set itself> except <the wrong characters
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT0FdXV1NQzNaVw9IAUldPc3/qckZ@QppCurRBgax6lwwnq6Jnrmp@n8A)

Comment: It's easier to see where your code ends and the explanation begins if you put the explanation in a separate programming puzzle. Also, consider adding a [try it online](https://tio.run/#j) link to your answer so that users can test your submission. Besides that, great first post and welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
n"n\\\"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P08pLyYmRun///9KefkKMUpJicnZxTmJxRmpxTFKChmpRalKAA)

```
n          The intersection of
 "n\\\"    the string n, \, "
           with the input.
```

I tried to work around having to escape the quote with a backslash, but that just made it longer:

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
n:'""n:'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P89KXUkJSPz//x9IgUB5UWp5UWF5alpKcVpxYoySQmZxnnqJEgA)

```
n         The intersection of
  '"      the character "
 :        prepended to
  "n:'    the string n, :, '
          with the input.
```

Another attempt to eliminate backslashes, which would be two bytes shorter if it didn't need to remove duplicates:

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
uns"nsu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcW7DYAwDAXAVZ5cZwdqJqChyQ@MghIJ28r4Js0dmzR360JdzN3pGDNgR3kK7qr41uOCckWKuckbhasEJFNExeRFHqLbSZ1@)

```
u          Without duplicate elements,
 n         the intersection of
  s        the string representation of
   "nsu    the string n, s, u
           with the input.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 10 bytes

```
#QupIN#Qvv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f9fObC0wNNPObCs7P9/Tz8A)

Turns out the lazy way worse than doing it generally because I can't get a quote within a quote nicely. `"IN_+"'"_+IN`

```
#Q  #Push the code onto the stack
up  #Convert to string
IN  #Intersection
#Q  #Make sure a #Q is captured
vv  #Drop the resulting push
```

Comment: @a'_' Do you mean because it produces an extra "\"? If so, then adding a "Q" cures it. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f9fKdDTL15dW0ldKV7b0y/w/39PP3UlAA "Burlesque – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 150 bytes

```
,[[>+>+<<-]>>[-[->>+<<]+>>]+>+[--<[-<<]>.>+>[-]]-<[-<<]>[-]<,] !"#$%&'()*/0123456789:;=?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\\^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJzraTttO28ZGN9bOLlo3WtcOxInVtrMDYu1oXV2baF0g304PqCpaNzYWxgeybXRiFRSVlFVU1dQ1NLX0DQyNjE1MzcwtLK2sbe0dHJ2cXVzd3D08vbx9fP38AwKDgkNCw8IjIqNiYuLiExKTklNS09IzMrOyc3Lz8gsKi4pLSsvKKyqrqmtq6/7/BxoGBAA)

Support 32-126

main code(set remove dup) 62