# Is this an anagram of its own source code?

Tags: code-golf, string, self-referential

I like anagrams. I like programs that reference their own source code. So this challenge combines them!

**Input.**
The input to the program could be anything, including letters, numbers, symbols, you name it.

**Output.**
A truthy value if the input's characters can be rearranged to give the source code, and a falsy value if the input's characters cannot. This does include spaces: the input must have the same number of spaces as the source code.

**Scoring.**
Lowest amount of characters wins, with one exception: the program must use at least three distinct characters.

Comment: Related: [Write the shortest self-identifying program (a quine variant)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11370/write-the-shortest-self-identifying-program-a-quine-variant)

Comment: Related: [Is it a substring of itself?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/148022/is-it-a-substring-of-itself)

Comment: [An almost identical challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/90154/58563) was (arguably) closed as a dupe of the more generic [anagram detection](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1294/58563) challenge.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a duplicate of either of the challenges linked by @Arnauld. I’ve voted to close as a duplicate of the generic anagram question, as I agree with the arguments made in the comments of the closed question. For those who disagree, consider voting to reopen the older question and closing this as a duplicate of that