# Levenshtein Your Source

Tags: code-golf, string, quine, edit-distance

> [The Levenshtein edit distance between two strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is the minimum possible number of insertions, deletions, or substitutions to convert one word into another word. In this case, each insertion, deletion and substitution has a cost of 1.
>
> For example, the distance between `roll` and `rolling` is 3, because deletions cost 1, and we need to delete 3 characters. The distance between `toll` and `tall` is 1, because substitutions cost 1.
>
> [Stolen from original Levenshtein question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/67474/65836)

Your task is to calculate the Levenshtein edit difference between an input string and your source. This is tagged [quine](/questions/tagged/quine), so cheating quines (for example, reading your source code) are *not* allowed.

#### Rules

- The input will be non-empty and will be composed of ASCII, unless your source contains non-ASCII, in which case the input may include Unicode. Regardless, the Levenshtein distance will be measured in characters, not bytes.
- The output is the minimum Levenshtein edit distance of the input and your source.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer, in bytes, wins.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13601/65836)

Comment: I was going to suggest making the score the output of your program when run through itself, but then I realized...

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/89400/42963).

Comment: Retina is so close to winning this with an empty program...

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://www.python.org/) 2 + [sequtils](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sequtils), 101 bytes

```py
from sequtils import*;_='from sequtils import*;_=%r;print edit(_%%_,input())';print edit(_%_,input())
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>278</s> 258 bytes

```python
t=input();s,f='t=input();s,f=%r,lambda m,n:m or n if m*n<1else-~min(f(m-1,n),f(m,n-1),f(m-1,n-1)-((s%%s)[m-1]==t[n-1]));print f(len(s%%s),len(t))',lambda m,n:m or n if m*n<1else-~min(f(m-1,n),f(m,n-1),f(m-1,n-1)-((s%s)[m-1]==t[n-1]));print f(len(s%s),len(t))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY2xDsIgFEV/hYXAM48BRytf0nSoKUQSeCXlObj460h1ME4ubuee3OSUO19XOrbGLlK5sYahYnDqe8oN05wvyywy0imLdRMkYhD5QGfrU/XmkSPpoLOxSIAdkIx9wW46Gq2rlBXGLibneOxyAhjKFolF0MnT@4A7MYD6T/JX8RNsTS0@qCc)

This is just the usual quine in Python, mixed with the Levenshtein algorithm from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102910/68615). Note that it gets <s>quite</s> *extremely* (thanks to Mr. Xcoder :P) slow.

Comment: Does this work for `l(s%s,input())` (not sure)?

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `D`, 10 bytes

```
`:qp꘍`:qp꘍
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=D&code=%60%3Aqp%EA%98%8D%60%3Aqp%EA%98%8D&inputs=%60%3Apq%EA%98%8D%60%3Apq%EA%98%8D&header=&footer=)

Thanks to Aaron Miller for this one.

```
`:qp `:qp  # Standard quine
    ꘍    ꘍ # Levenshtein distance
```

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `D`, 13 bytes

```
`q\`:Ė\`+꘍`:Ė
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=D&code=%60q%5C%60%3A%C4%96%5C%60%2B%EA%98%8D%60%3A%C4%96&inputs=%27%60q%5C%60%3A%C4%96%5C%60%2B%EA%98%8D%60%3Ap%27&header=&footer=)

```
`q\`:Ė\`+ `:Ė # Standard eval quine (see https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/232956/100664)
         ꘍    # Leveshtein distance with input
```

[10 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=D&code=%60q%E2%80%9B%3A%C4%96%2B%EA%98%8D%60%3A%C4%96&inputs=%27%60q%5C%60%3A%C4%96%5C%60%2B%EA%98%8D%60%3Ap%27&header=&footer=) in Vyxal 2.6, whiich hasn't been released yet

Comment: [10 bytes using the other Vyxal quine](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=D&code=%60%3Aqp%EA%98%8D%60%3Aqp%EA%98%8D&inputs=%60%3Apq%EA%98%8D%60%3Apq%EA%98%8D&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 210 bytes

```hs
main=interact$show.((x++show x)%);x@(a:c)%y@(b:d)|a==b=c%d|1>0=1+minimum[x%d,c%y,c%d];x%y=length$x++y;x="main=interact$show.((x++show x)%);x@(a:c)%y@(b:d)|a==b=c%d|1>0=1+minimum[x%d,c%y,c%d];x%y=length$x++y;x="
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM882M68ktSgxuUSlOCO/XE9Do0JbG8RSqNBU1bSucNBItErWVK100EiyStGsSbS1TbJNVk2pMbQzsDXUzs3My8wtzY2uUE3RSVatBOKUWOsK1UrbnNS89JIMFaBZldYVtkp0s2gY@slQKREA)

Computes the levenshtein distance modified from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Recursive).  (I wrote the code there too)  This is combined with a standard quine mechanism.  Not much special here.

If you want to play around with it I suggest making edits towards the end of the string.  The algorithm is more or less \$O(n+m^4)\$ where \$n\$ is the location of the difference between the input and the source, and \$m\$ is the length of the string after the first difference.  So if you add a character to the front of this the compute time is exponential with the length of input and you won't see your result on tio.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 135 bytes

```python
exec(s:="l=lambda a,b:min(l(A:=a[1:],B:=b[1:])-(a[0]==b[0]),l(A,b),l(a,B))+1if b>''<a else len(a+b);print(l('exec(s:=%r)'%s,input()))")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BCsMgFESvIoGgn/xCQjfF1kJzjeDi21oqGCtqoTm9NYuuZh4Mb@JWXu9wPMVUq/3au8hSdV55Ws2DGKGRqwvCi5tUtExS4yyV2QscBC2jVo1GDdgWaPYgnAGGyT2ZuXJ@IWZ9tszbIGgwcI7JhdJ8/H/WJ@B9RhfipwgA6KDWzeYf)

took my solution of levenstein distance (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233868/103772) and adapted it to a quine. It is very (very) slow but it works

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 113 bytes

This is a [valid](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13638/72349) quine.

```
f=t=>[...t].map((v,j)=>x=x.map((w,k)=>q=k--?Math.min(q,w,x[k]-(v==u[k]))+1:j+1),x=[...[,...u=`f=${f}`].keys()])|q
```

```js
f=t=>[...t].map((v,j)=>x=x.map((w,k)=>q=k--?Math.min(q,w,x[k]-(v==u[k]))+1:j+1),x=[...[,...u=`f=${f}`].keys()])|q

console.log(f('f=t=>[...t].map((v,j)=>x=x.map((w,k)=>q=k--?Math.min(q,w,x[k]-(v==u[k]))+1:j+1),x=[...[,...u=`f=${f}`].keys()])|q'));
console.log(f('%'));
console.log(f('12345'));
```

Idea stolen from other answer.

Comment: "This is a valid quine" - actually, I'm not sure there's any clear consensus in that meta thread you linked. And in fact, by a few votes, the "this is cheating" option is actually winning.