# Is it a substring of itself?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, quine

Given a string, return whether the string is a substring of the program's source code.

Standard quine rules apply, meaning you cannot read your own source code. The length of the input is guaranteed to be less than or equal to the length of the program. You may return any two distinct values, not necessarily truthy and falsey values. You may also submit a function, rather than a full program.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins!

#### An example

If your source code is `print(input() = False)`, it should return True for `nt(i` but False for `tupn`.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11370/31716)

Comment: Is a function allowed?

Comment: @totallyhuman as with most challenges, yes.

Comment: [Also related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/89400/42963).

Comment: guys mentioning all related questions that don’t make it a duplicate is unnecessary.

Comment: @StanStrum It is not to point out duplicates, it is to show related challenges that people might be interested in and to show them on the sidebar to the right.

Comment: Can the input be empty? (Actually, can the _code_ be empty?)

Comment: @Lynn No, the code cannot be empty

Comment: -1 because this is a [generalized narcissist](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8595/61384)

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 41 bytes

```python
s="print input()in's=%r;exec s'%s";exec s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9hWqaAoM69EITOvoLREQzMzT73YVrXIOrUiNVmhWF21WAnK/P9fHaxQHQA)

Comment: As a reference, the Python 3 port is [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9hWqaAoM69EIzOvoLREQzMzT73YVrXIOrUiNVmjWFNdtVhTCcYhTTUA).

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), 25 bytes

```javascript
f=s=>('f='+f).includes(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnBDYAwCADAcYAYuwHu0rRgakgxoq6P3veO@tZo1zjvdXqXTOXgDUEZFqUyZrOnS2BQNp/hJsV8R0X4C4jyAw)

I'm personally not a fan of this, but [it's allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13638/68615).

### Alternate (invalid?) solution, 19 bytes

This takes input as a regex.

```javascript
f=s=>s.test('f='+f)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zbbY1q5YryS1uERDPc1WXTtN839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahj5QTl9T8z8A)

Comment: Doesn't it read itself?

Comment: @Adám https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13638/68615

Comment: What is the purpose of explicitly mentioning `(Node.js)`? Doesn't it work in browsers too?

Comment: @ThePirateBay Works as expected in Chrome.

Comment: @steenbergh. I know, of course, but I'm wondering what is the purpose of mentioning `Node.js` while it works on any JavaScript engine.

Comment: @ThePirateBay There are some differences between the Javascript implementations of Node, Spidermonkey and ... the other one. I guess it's mentioned to avoid hitting one of those differences, though in this case I think it's a bit superfluous.

Comment: @steenbergh. Well, I think the only reason for it is because he just copied *"Code Golf submission"* field from TIO without modifying anything, which includes `Node.js` next to `JavaScript`. I agree, it is superfluous in this case and may be confusing to people which see this answer.

Comment: You guys are thinking way ahead, it's just from the TIO template. :P

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, <s>124</s> 112 bytes (function)

```java
p->{String s="p->{String s=%c%s%1$c;return s.format(s,34,s).contains(p);}";return s.format(s,34,s).contains(p);}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jY9Bi8IwEIXv/RVD2UIKGlj0VvQf6MXj4mFMo0TbSchMBZH@9my624sLC14GHvNm3veueMelD5au7S2ZDplhh46eBYAjsfGMxsJ@kgAn7zuLBEYdJDq6QKibvBiLPFhQnIE9EGwgheX2OXt4U76oylRcfX6YJloZIgHrs489iuLFar3gWhtPkglY5e9j@Z4tNRNDGE5dZphR7t610GfLTPt1BKx/ixweLLbXfhAd8ko6UqSNKv8GlfVPwf8PIlLr@5w4BczusRhT@gY)

---

Here is it as full program instead (to see one of the reasons why functions are allowed on PPCG, because some languages -like Java- require very verbose mandatory boilerplate code for full programs).

## Java 8, <s>226</s> 214 bytes (full program)

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){String s="interface M{static void main(String[]a){String s=%c%s%1$c;System.out.print(s.format(s,34,s).contains(a[0]));}}";System.out.print(s.format(s,34,s).contains(a[0]));}}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##ncxBCsIwEIXhq4RiIIEaFN0Vj9BVl6WLIU0llUxKZixI6dljQHCvux8e35thhWNcHM7jI2eP7NIE1ol2Iwb2VqzRjyKAR9Vx8njvB9DbJwXdqp@FtJLk@WCb7kXsgolPNkvZWJGZYgpQor5ca9LGRuRyQwr606B1s@/VXyrn/CVv)

---

**Explanation:**

- The `String s` contains the unformatted source code.
- `%s` is used to input this String into itself with the `s.format(...)`.
- `%c`, `%1$c` and the `34` are used to format the double-quotes.
- `s.format(s,34,s)` puts it all together.

And then `.contains(...)` is used to check if this source code contains the given input.

Comment: This gives me true for **all** strings when I "Try it online".

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors not for me... Are you sure you don't add arguments each time? Only one argument is used. You have to run the program changing the argument each time you make a new test.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire You are correct, I used the TIO page wrong. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 28 bytes

```
?instr(B+B,;)#?instr(B+B,;)#
```

This prints 0 if the input is not a substring of the source, and X otherwise where X is the (first) index of the substring.

### Explanation

```
Latter part:
#?instr(B+B,;)#   Define a string literal B$ with a copy of the source

First part:
?                 PRINT
 instr(   , )     the index of
           ;          the cmd line parameter A$
       B+B            in B$ concatenated with itself
```

`#` defines a string literal in QBIC, and assigns it to the first available string variable. That is `B$` in this program, because `A$` is already taken by `;` (read a string from cmd line). Then, everything up to the delimiter is fed into the literal; the delimiter is a backtick - which also makes it the only ASCII char not includable in string lits. In this case, QBIC doesn't need a backtick, because the literal is terminated at the end of the code by QBIC's auto-close feature. For more information on QBIC's literals, see [the Showcase thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/showcase-of-languages/86385#86385).

Comment: What is `A` in this context?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing a little error on my side, should've been`B` and an explanation is added.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, <s>43</s>, 28 bytes

```
[[ $BASH_COMMAND = *"$1"* ]]
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifll@kUKyQmafg5BisoB4draACZHjEO/v7@jr6uSjYKmgpqRgqaSnExqrjl1ZQt1ZIyVcoTi1R0NVVUFIpVvqPT/n/1OSMfAUldRVDdSsFFQ0NRRV7TU0lrpT8vNT/AA)

Comment: I don't know Bash, but can this be golfed further by removing a lot of the whitespace?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I don't think so, `typeset` formats it like this AFAICT. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYwxDoMwEAR7v2JjnXQ@pBRpQVEeYlGE4BNpMMrREJS3O4ZtphjNDk@bStEg2BEjKKzbkiytuCpUcEdDtwZ9735F8weG9wwWuB0OdZHBR1NxhF/uMObTKDyZ75BeU4ZnMm7re7jQQ8S7Mc@p/AE "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: but may be improved maybe using another technique

Comment: just found another solution

Comment: What does `$1` do?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing it 's the first argument in a script, for example `script.sh '[['` or a function `f '='`, the result is the exit status `0` means success, `1` failed

Comment: the double quotes arround `$1` prevent wildcard characters `*` or `?` inside argument to have a special meaning and are taken literally

Comment: This reads the source file, no?

Comment: not really, it's a special variable, see also https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13638/68615, it's part of language, it's not the same as accessing to the source

Comment: Your first solution is more instructive to me, but a nice find with that environment variable. +1

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 92 bytes

```hs
import Data.List;f s=isInfixOf s$(++)<*>show$"import Data.List;f s=isInfixOf s$(++)<*>show$"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRzyezuMQ6TaHYNrPYMy8ts8IfyFbR0NbWtNGyK87IL1dRIk31/9zEzDwFW4XMvJLUosTkEgUVBZCEgp5C2n@irQAA) Obvious extension of the standard quine. Getting rid of the import would be nice, but I doubt `isInfixOf` can be computed in a shorter amount of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 33 bytes

```
!StringFreeQ[ToString[#0], #1] &
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@18xuKQoMy/drSg1NTA6JB/Ci1Y2iNVRUDaMVVBT@B8AFClxSItWIqhUKfY/AA)

Comment: nice! +1. I see comments for "ungolfed syntax" coming ;-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
“;⁾vṾƓẇ”vṾ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxzrR437yh7u3Hds8sNd7Y8a5oLY//@rQznqAA)

#### How it works

```
“;⁾vṾƓẇ”vṾ  Main link. No arguments.

“;⁾vṾƓẇ”    Set the left argument and the return value to ';⁾vṾƓẇ'.
         Ṿ  Uneval; yield '“;⁾vṾƓẇ”'.
        v   Dyadic eval; eval ';⁾vṾƓẇ' with argument '“;⁾vṾƓẇ”'.

  ⁾vṾ       Yield 'vṾ'.
 ;          Append it to '“;⁾vṾƓẇ”', yielding the source code.
     Ɠ      Read a string from STDIN.
      ẇ     Check if it's a substring of the source code.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 72 bytes

I now understand what people mean when they say that quine problems are just variations on the classic quine.

```
x="~y=contains\"x=\$(repr(x));\$x\",y)";~y=contains("x=$(repr(x));$x",y)
```

### Explanation

```
#Defines x to be the next line of the source, with the help of escaping characters
x="~y=contains\"x=\$(repr(x));\$x\",y)"; 
#Interpolates together a comparison string, including repr(x), the re-escaped from of x, and x itself, for comparison. 
~y=contains("x=$(repr(x));$x",y)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `D`, 56 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 7 bytes

```
`Iǎc`Iǎc
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJEPSIsIiIsImBJx45jYEnHjmMiLCIiLCJJx45jIl0=)

### Explained

```
`Iǎc`Iǎc­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
      ǎ   # ‎⁡Does all substrings of 
`Iǎc`     # ‎⁢  The string "Iǎc"
     I    # ‎⁣  With a version surrounded in backticks prepended to itself
       c  # ‎⁤Contain the input?
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 60 + 2 (-pl) bytes

```
$_=(sprintf$a=q($_=(sprintf$a=q(%s),$a)=~/\Q$_/),$a)=~/\Q$_/
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lajuKAoM68kTSXRtlADna9arKmjkqhpW6cfE6gSr4/CIaybC7dmLkpsJqhZQQG35n/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULcgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0"D34çýIå"D34çýIå
```

Modification of the default [quine](/questions/tagged/quine) [`0"D34çý"D34çý`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97899/52210) by adding `Iå`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fQMnF2OTw8sN7PQ8vRWL@/w/mAwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
0                    # Push 0 to the stack
                     #  STACK: [0]
 "D34çýIå"           # Push the string 'D34çýIå' to the stack
                     #  STACK: [0, 'D34çýIå']
          D          # Duplicate this string
                     #  STACK: [0, 'D34çýIå', 'D34çýIå']
           34ç       # Push '"' to the stack
                     #  STACK: [0, 'D34çýIå', 'D34çýIå', '"']
              ý      # Join the stack by this '"' delimiter
                     #  STACK: ['0"D34çýIå"D34çýIå']
               I     # Take the input
                     #  STACK: ['0"D34çýIå"D34çýIå', 'Iå"D']
                å    # Check if it's a substring of the source code
                     #  STACK [1]
                     # (Output the top of the stack implicitly)
```